# remove valid verification url requirement php

Tags: php

class function - How can I run it by removing the url requirement?
class bitcoin_tools::valid_address / I want it to work without part.

index.php

```
<?php require_once('includes/classes/tools.class.php');?>
       <h2>Valid Address Checker</h2>
       <?php if( isset($_REQUEST['address']) ):?>
          <?php if( empty($_REQUEST['address']) ):?>
             <div class="error">Please provide a bitcoin address. <a href="valid-address">Try Again?</a></div>
       
             <?php $address = strip_tags($_REQUEST['address']);?>
             <?php $valid   = bitcoin_tools::valid_address($_REQUEST['address']);?>
             <?php if($valid == true):?>
                <div class="success"><?php echo $address;?> is a valid bitcoin address. <br/><a href="valid-address">Check another?</a></div>
             <?php else:?>
                <div class="error"><?php echo $address;?> is a invalid bitcoin address. <br/><a href="valid-address">Check another?</a></div>
             <?php endif;?>
          <?php endif;?>
   
          <form method="get">
             <div class="input-group ">
                <input name="address" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Bitcoin address">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Check</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>
```

tools.class.php

class bitcoin_tools {

```
   public static function http_request($url) {
      $data = @file_get_contents($url);
      return $data;
   }

   public static function valid_address($address) {
      $data = self::http_request('https://blockchain.info/address/' . $address . '?limit=0&format=json');
      $data = json_decode($data, true);
      return (isset($data['address']) ? true : false);
   }


}
```

Comment: As an aside, any good IDE will warn you that `return (isset($data['address']) ? true : false);` is more simply expressed as `return isset($data['address']);`

Comment: @mickmackusa i couldn't succeed. Can you help